# Finding Euler path using powers of adjacency

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, eulerian-path, adjacency-matrix

Context: I'm studying an introductory course to Discrete Applied Mathematics, and am new to the context of graphs.

Knowing that a graph can be represented as an adjacency matrix, say we have the graph

$G = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
\end{bmatrix}$

I know we can look at $G^n$ to find the number of paths which connect any two vertexes given by $n$ walked paths. Trying to use $G^{vertexes}$, I thought I could check how many possible solutions for an Euler circuit there were based on the initially chosen vertex.

I quickly noticed that there was a flaw in my thinking: this allowed both paths and vertexes to be repeated on the path, which is not allowed in the definition of an Eulerian cycle.

I know I can see if an Eulerian cycle exists counting the number of vertexes in the graph having odd and even edges joining other vertexes.

- If all vertexes have an even number, or exactly two uneven, of connected lines, there must exist at least one Eulerian cycle.
- If there is exactly one, or more than two uneven vertexes, the Eulerian cycle doesn't exist.

This tells me nothing about where the starting position must be (unless there are two uneven ones), or the trajectory of the path.

Is there any property I can use to limit the amount of repetitions of paths/vertexes, using the exponentiation technique, in order to see what starting position are valid? Are there any other thing I should know about Eulerian circuits?

Comment: I don't think powers of the adjacency matrix are a good tool for thinking about Euler circuits. Your analysis suggests why.

Comment: You can turn it into a Markov chain matrix by probabilistic normalization and then count relative probability distributions in steady state. Then you will get how many Euler circuits each node belongs to.

Comment: @mathreadler Could you further explain in an extended answer?

Comment: @mazunki Okay. I will try answer later this week. I am working right now so I cant promise exactly when.

Answer (score 2):

My comment above with Markov chain probability matrices was a bit hasted and only gave me exact number in some special cases.

---

I will instead present a more exact algorithm for you.

We will need a couple of *building blocks*:

1. Adjacency matrix $\bf M$ of dimension $N\times N$.
2. Matrix multiplication.
3. [Hadamard/Schur (elementwise) product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices)) $(\otimes)$.
4. A specific circuit-remover matrix ${\bf O}={\bf 1 1} ^T{\bf - I}$, Where $\bf 1$ is the column vector of $N$ ones.

($\bf O$ is basically a logically inverted unit matrix, $0$ on diagonal and $1$ everywhere else)

Now define the matrix : $$\cases{{\bf T}_0 = {\bf M}\\{\bf T}_{k+1} = {\bf M}({\bf O \otimes T}_k)}$$

Then calculate the sum $${\bf s}=\sum_{k=0}^{N-1} \text{diag}({\bf T}_k)$$

Where diag is the operator that makes a vector from the diagonal elements. For example $$\text{diag}\left(\begin{bmatrix}1&2&13\\2&3&4\\13&4&5\end{bmatrix}\right) = [1,3,5]^T$$

You can note that if $\bf O$ was matrix filled with ones then ${\bf T}_k = {\bf M}^{k-1}$ (ordinary iterated matrix multiplication "power") which is what you realized could not be the case. So we only needed do a quite minor modification to your first idea.

I almost forgot to mention, the $\bf s$ vector will be a vector containing integers how many paths from position back to same position **passing any node on the way maximally 1 time**.

Comment: Wow, I that's a lot of information to take in at the same time. I have a few questions. From what I understood: The Hadamard product $O⊗T_{k}$ you mention is basically the "same" as a traditional sum of matrices, but replacing each sum sign with a standard product, I understand. And then you multiply the adjacency matrix with the result of the result. $T_{k}$ is the matrix showing the number of paths from one vertex to another using $k+1$ "steps". Why did you use $11^{T}$? What does the 11 mean? What does T mean? +

Comment: + You say $s$ is a vector, but what I see is a scalar number from the sum of the diagonal(s?) of a the matrix (or matrices?) $T_{k}$. The questions I have might arise from not having some mathematical base which is expected, nor experience using the sum notation. Also, you mention nodes, for $s$, and not edges, which led me to another question. Isn't an Eulerian path defined as a path where each edge is walked on maximum once, and not each vertex?

Comment: I added link to Hadamard prod and description of "diag" operator.

Comment: Thanks. I will give it a shot once I come home.

Comment: $1$ is column vector full of N ones. T is transpose. So ${\bf 11}^T$ is N x N matrix full of ones.